# httppost cause the app to crash

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i'm trying to send post request to my PHP page through java in android studio

first i tried httppost and the app crashed after pressing the key

then i read that i have to use new thread and i did so but still

the app crashes

here is the code :

```
 public void send () {
    final String name,phone,fb;
    EditText one,two,three;
    one=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    two=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    three=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    name=one.getText().toString();
    phone=two.getText().toString();
    fb=three.getText().toString();
    Thread T=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://test.com/test.php");
            try {
                List <NameValuePair> nameValuePairs= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("number",phone));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fbname",fb));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response= httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
        }
    });
    T.start();
}
```

Log : http://pastebin.com/KQ9Y3rrG

Comment: @Rami  http://pastebin.com/MtgG62G2

Comment: Add `e.printStackTrace();` to your `catch` block and update your logtrace.

Comment: @Rami http://pastebin.com/KQ9Y3rrG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the permissions for communicating with the internet set in your manifest file. If not, it will throw a `SecurityException` and break your app.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Other than that, I can't see anything in your log that could be the cause an exception.

**Update**

After checking the code provided by the user the problem was coming from the fact that the `onClick` event was supposed to trigget the `send()` method while unknowingly defining it without the required `View v` parameter.

The solution (to this problem, this doesn't mean it will make the `httppost` work) is simple to add the parameter to the definition of the method:

```
public void send (View v) {
```

Comment: i'm sure that i have the permission : (

Comment: Manifest seems fine, what about the rest of the activity?

Comment: And where are you calling `send()`?

Comment: <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="send"
        android:layout_marginBottom="59dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76214/discussion-between-juan-and-user2973413).